# How to install / run freefem++

Tags: apt

After `sudo apt-get install freefem++` ran successfully, my Ubuntu 14. 04 system does not seem to recognize the command "freefem++". Any ideas?

Things seem to be in /usr/share/doc/freefem++ (but no executables).

```
sudo dpkg -I ./var/cache/apt/archives/freefem++_3.26-2-3_amd64.deb
```

Did not  much either.

Not sure what to do next to get this software to work.

Comment: Have you checked "Freefem++" instead of "freefem++"?

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an introduction [how to install FreeFem++ on Ubuntu 13.04 and Linux Mint 16/17](http://www.tobias-rienmueller.de/install-freefem-on-ubuntu-13-04-or-linux-mint-1617/). Maybe it would be useful for somebody.

---

For the installation we use the standard Linux Terminal.

It depends on your system whether you have to install “Mercurial” first. This you can do by:

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial
```

Then I used the latest version of FreeFem++ which you can get by:

```
hg clone http://www.freefem.org/ff++/ff++
```

Use the command:

```
cd ff++
```

to go into the directory where the “hg” downloaded the files. Here you start:

```
autoreconf -i
```

To have all necessary packages for FreeFem++ use apt-get install routine with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install bison curl flex patch rsync wget g++ gfortran libx11-dev libice-dev libsm-dev libxau-dev libxdmcp-dev libxrender-dev libxft-dev libxext-dev libxpm-dev libxt-dev m4 make mesa-common-dev libglu1-mesa-dev mpi-default-bin mpi-default-dev libvtk5-dev libopenblas-dev libfftw3-dev libsuitesparse-dev cmake bzip2
```

To get the graphic interface write:

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev
```

Now we have all stuff to compile the files with:

```
./configure
```

or use:

```
./configure –enable-download
```

for more software packages, like solvers and other additional stuff. At the end you get a message since some packages are still missing, if yes use the apt-get install routine again. Afterwards you can use:

```
download/getall
```

to get still more additional solvers and fftw packages. Now for compiling use:

```
make
```

This took nearly 20 minutes on my HP Elitebook 8440p. The compiling can be tested by:

```
make check
```

To install FreeFem++ use:

```
sudo make install
```

Now FreeFem++ works on your Linux Distribution.

Answer (score 1):

`freefem++` only "Provides the binaries of the FreeFem++ FE suite". Original package is `freefem` which is "PDE oriented language using Finite Element Method". See [Packages.Ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=freefem&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all).

So you need to install `freefem` package as suggested by @Braiam.

```
sudo apt-get install freefem
```

Comment: Turns out freefem is obsolete and replaced by freefem++. After many dependency package installs there are still remaining problems with the freefem++ install. Have posted to their website forum. If I get freefem++ installed and working well, I will post details.

Answer (score 0):

just run this way

```
FreeFem++ yourfile.edp
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with packaging and naming with that package.

The one biting you is: You need to write the name in its obscure way.

The name of the main program is not called like we 
would expect from the package name, with lowercase letters `freefem++`, but `FreeFem++`. Even with an intermittent uppercase letter.

So you should be able to run in like this from a shell:

```
$ FreeFem++ ... ...
```

Note it's uppercase, but different ellsewhere too. So a good shell kan not just offer the uppercase variant of what you search: `femfem++` can not be replaced by `Femfem++`.

Actually, femfem is referred to by three different names - there is also `ff`as a prefix.

(I would call this mixub a bug,, but it's hard to sort that out late in the game)

Take a look, the package FemFem++ contains other binaries:

```
$ apt-file list --fixed-string freefem++
freefem++: /usr/bin/FreeFem++
freefem++: /usr/bin/FreeFem++-mpi
freefem++: /usr/bin/FreeFem++-nw
freefem++: /usr/bin/cvmsh2
freefem++: /usr/bin/ff-c++
freefem++: /usr/bin/ff-get-dep
freefem++: /usr/bin/ff-mpirun
freefem++: /usr/bin/ff-pkg-download
freefem++: /usr/bin/ffbamg
freefem++: /usr/bin/ffglut
freefem++: /usr/bin/ffmedit
[ ... docs follow ...]
```